# Show userpic of Twitter account on the page using TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I use http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth PHP library for reaching Twitter REST API:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    require("config.php");
    require("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");
    if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) &&
       !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) &&
       !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'])
    )
    {                        
        $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);  
        $access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']); 
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token; 
        $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
        // ?...
?>
```

How can I render the Twitter userpic on the HTML page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

Just do this:

```
echo '<img src="'.$user_info->profile_image_url.'"/>';
```

The [`account/verify_credentials`](http://bit.ly/bWv82N) call returns all the user variables. So, no need to do another call.

**[Old Answer]**

Use [`users show`](http://bit.ly/b2RNDN) method. It returns a field called `profile_image_url` which you need. It's the URL of the photo of the user.